# Bigbluebutton Java Security issue

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, remote-desktop, bigbluebutton

I am working in bigbluebutton 0.8.1. I had setup the development environment in my local(ubuntu 10.04) and desktop sharing is working fine.

Later i created new bbb-desktop-applet jar, using the url https://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/wiki/081DevelopingBigBlueButton#Developing_Deskshare. And then moved the newly created jar to this location var/www/bigbluebutton/client in ubuntu machine and then restarted the server. I can able to create and join the room, but not able to share my desktop, getting below error. Already I added the url in exception site list in java control panel but still it is not working.i stuck up with this issue.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the developers of BigBlueButton.

You need to sign the modified desktop sharing jar file with a valid code signing certificate (not a self-signed certificate); otherwise, the browser will give you a very strong warning (such as the above) that warns the user they are trying to run an untrusted applet.

This is not a security issue with BigBlueButton; rather, it's the absence of a valid certificate signature with your modified desktop sharing applet.

Regards,... Fred

Comment: Thanks for your reply Fred.Could you please explain how can we get valid code signing certificate. Also we are using only http protocol, not https. Please guide me here.

Note - we are using below certificate to create the bigbluebutton jar. 
/home/firstuser/dev/bigbluebutton/deskshare/applet/tstcert.crt